# How to fetch curl response JSON in yaml script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to assign my response obj values to an array in my bitbucket.yml script. But it returns me undefined.
Below is the curl response:

```
{
"pagelen": 500,
"values": [
    {
        "status": "modified",
        "old": {
            "path": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml",
            "escaped_path": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml",
            "type": "commit_file",
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{{workspace}}/{{repo_slug}}/src/{{commit_hash}}/bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
                }
            }
        },
        "lines_removed": 1,
        "lines_added": 1,
        "new": {
            "path": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml",
            "escaped_path": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml",
            "type": "commit_file",
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{{workspace}}/{{repo_slug}}/src/{{commit_hash}}/bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "diffstat"
    }
],
"page": 1,
"size": 1
```

}

Here, I want to assign the filenames from the response "values[i].old["path"]" to an array with the help of a loop which would iterate over values and get the filenames and deploy them :

```
for(i = 0; i<FILES.length; i++){ 
 run deploy FILES[i].old["path"]}
```

Below I used bitbuckets API to curl my response and assign it to a var "FILES"

FILES=$(node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).values' "$(curl https://${BITBUCKET_USERNAME}:${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE/$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG/diffstat/$BITBUCKET_COMMIT)")

With the above API im able to assign the values array from the response to my variable FILE in my pipelines.yml script, but now the major blocker is to loop over the FILE variable and run my deploy cmd one by one over the filenames.

Any leads would be helpful.

PS: I am trying to implement CD process using bitbucket pipelines using javascript/nodejs as preferred language